# Devise/Rails - Access cookie information before creating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

When registering new users via Devise in Rails 5, I need to check if a cookie exists and if so store data from the cookie to a newly created user record.  It also utilizes OmniAuth to create users from Facebook.  I'm having trouble finding a way to tap into Devise's user creation and be able to access cookie information.

If I implement this directly in the `RegistrationController` after a user is created, I have to repeat it in the OmniAuth callbacks, which is not very DRY.  Is there a better place or method to hook into this?

I came across the `new_with_session` method when building a new resource, but unfortunately that only gives access to the session, not cookies.

Comment: Seems to used to merge/keep old cookie which generate by anonymous user?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question @seaify-Freelancer.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Why can't you define the logic in one place, and then call the method you've defined from both `RegistrationsController` and the OmniAuth callbacks? That solves your DRY problem, because you've written the logic once and are calling it from different places.

Comment: The OmniAuth callback uses the model to perform some custom logic and may either create a user or update an existing user.  It didn't feel right to pass cookies into the model at that point.  I was hoping for one point of entry where Devise was handling it, but I can refactor my OmniAuth logic a bit in order to go about it the way you suggested

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to do this with regular registrations.  With OmniAuth I create the user myself, but Devise handles it for other registrations.  How do I check and inject cookie data into the user model when devise is creating the user?